# "Не отрывающийся взгляд"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Наткнулся в интернете на один демотиватор. Собственно, ошибками в подписях сейчас никого не удивишь, к сожалению, но там подпись гласила: "Дороже всех медалей и наград ее *не отрывающийся* взгляд".
Вообще, по отношению к взгляду можно сказать "не отрывающийся"? По-моему, лучше было бы сказать "неотрывный". В общем, есть ошибка в этом демотиваторе или нет?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, "неотрывающийся взгляд" - вполне нормальное словосочетание, причем "не" пишется слитно

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке есть фразеологизм "Взгляд не отрывается". Голос его, без намерения, был нежен, взгляд не отрывался от неё (Гончаров. Обрыв). Так что это выражение вполне нормальное и не противоречит нормам русского языка.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, неотрывный. А "неотрывающийся" – не есть хороший русский язык. Жаль, что замечают очень немногие.